# Equivelant of MySQL Limit in Oracle.Query includes several tables?

Tags: mysql, oracle, limit

I have the following query in MySQL and want to convert it to Oracle. I tried row_number() function and subqueries in Oracle but could not make it run properly. The query is kinda weird and covers multiple tables.

Original MySQL Query:

```
select DISTINCT uc.virtual_clip_id, uc.clip_id, uc.duration, uc.title,  
                uc.thumbnail,uc.filename, uc.description, uc.block_id_start, 
                uc.block_id_end, u.uname,uc.cdate, uc.ctime, uc.privacy_level, uc.user_id 
FROM
    user_clips uc, users u, user_like ul

WHERE 
     ul.user_id="+user_id+" and u.user_id=uc.user_id and  
     uc.virtual_clip_id=ul.virtual_clip_id and ul.like_status='1'
ORDER by 
      virtual_clip_id DESC
LIMIT "+offset+",4"
```

I could not find the proper statement to replace LIMIT so make the query run against Oracle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from 
 (
  select DISTINCT uc.virtual_clip_id, uc.clip_id, uc.duration, uc.title,  
                  uc.thumbnail,uc.filename, uc.description, uc.block_id_start, 
                  uc.block_id_end, u.uname,uc.cdate, uc.ctime, uc.privacy_level, uc.user_id 
                , row_number() over(order by uc.virtual_clip_id desc) rn
  FROM
      user_clips uc, users u, user_like ul
  WHERE 
       ul.user_id="+user_id+" and u.user_id=uc.user_id and  
       uc.virtual_clip_id=ul.virtual_clip_id and ul.like_status='1'
 )
where rn between "+offset+" and 4
```

Comment: First of thanks. This seems to work but I have one issue. I have 6 records in my table and I try to retrieve the ones matching my criteria in my specific range (offset to 4). When I run the query it returns the matching values even if they are out of desired range. Lets say my 6th record fits what query asks for but actually it is out of my range.I still see it among the returned records. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I think I figured it out. As I have a very few records in my table the number of records in the ordered set is less than my upper bound always. This upper bound is not for my entire table but the one ordered.

Comment: This query also works for me. Thank you very much. I couldnt vote up as i dont have enough reps

Comment: Yep I did it. I did not notice that "click" symbol :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a pain but you can use rownum

```
select * from
(
select rownum as row_number, base_data.* from
(
select DISTINCT uc.virtual_clip_id, uc.clip_id, uc.duration, uc.title,
 uc.thumbnail,uc.filename, uc.description, uc.block_id_start, uc.block_id_end, u.uname,uc.cdate, uc.ctime, uc.privacy_level, uc.user_id FROM user_clips uc, users u, user_like ul

WHERE ul.user_id="+user_id+" and u.user_id=uc.user_id and
 uc.virtual_clip_id=ul.virtual_clip_id and ul.like_status='1' 
) base_data
ORDER by virtual_clip_id DESC
) sorted
WHERE row_number <= X
```

The only reason I subselected twice was the distinct is performing a group and I kept the ordering outside of it, it could be done with a single subselect.

Comment: Well when I run this query (without LIMIT part, I believe u forget to remove it as it is the problem in Oracle) I get such an error:Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATA": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" I dont have any column named 'Data'

Comment: I originally used data as the alias and changed it to base_data, but forgot to change the reference, edited answer.

Comment: I see and I am kinda novice in this Oracle thing. I could not see it as an alias and though something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
select DISTINCT
    uc.virtual_clip_id
  , uc.clip_id
  , uc.duration
  , uc.title
  , uc.thumbnail
  , uc.filename
  , uc.description
  , uc.block_id_start
  , uc.block_id_end
  , u.uname
  , uc.cdate
  , uc.ctime
  , uc.privacy_level
  , uc.user_id
  , row_number() over(order by uc.virtual_clip_id DESC) row_nr
   FROM
    user_clips uc
  , users u
  , user_like ul
  WHERE
    ul.user_id         = "+user_id+"
and u.user_id          = uc.user_id
and uc.virtual_clip_id = ul.virtual_clip_id
and ul.like_status     = '1'
)
 where row_nr < 5 ;
```

Comment: When I run this query I receive the following error:                 Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. I checked the column names and they seem fine. Thanks. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I solved this error by changing it as "order by uc.virtual_clip_id DESC"

Comment: This query also works for me. Thank you very much. I couldnt vote up as i dont have enough reps.

Comment: @Jonathan O'Neil  glad to be of assistance!  sorry about missing the prefix there! (edited answer to reflect that)